# AS3: resize handler stretching image

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have an image loader that I am attempting to resize dynamically.
I would like to make sure that the aspect ratio is kept intact so that the image doesn't stretch.
When I reload the image (re-populate it with another image via the loader), there is a resize function that is called.  I would like to know what I might be doing wrong with this portion of the resize code:

```
var aspect:Number = width / height;
var cAspect:Number = _imageBoundary.width / _imageBoundary.height;

if (aspect <= cAspect) 
{
    _ldr.height = _imageBoundary.height;
    _ldr.width = aspect * _ldr.height;
}
else 
{
    _ldr.width = _imageBoundary.width;
    _ldr.height = _ldr.width / aspect;
}

_ldr.x = (_imageBoundary.width - _ldr.width) / 2 + _imageBoundary.x;
_ldr.y = (_imageBoundary.height - _ldr.height) / 2 + _imageBoundary.y;
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.
I am basing the larger portion of this on bhups's code.

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the first line should be

```
var aspect:Number = _ldr.content.width / _ldr.content.height;
```

Comment: Beautiful.  Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easy and reliable way is to use the Image class. 
You can see a good example here: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/06/28/maintaining-an-images-aspect-ratio-on-an-image-control-in-flex/.

the Image class may get dynamically change in its source field and load the image accordingly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reference-- Currently I am looking for an AS3 ONLY solution.